# Add multiple points to highchart using json

Tags: json, highcharts

I know this topic is discussed multiple times, but frankly I have still no idea how to solve my problem.
So a little help is highly appreciable.

I have a function to take the json data like this..

```
function requestData() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'XYZ.php',
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[0];
            shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                          // longer than 20

        // add the point
        chart.series[0].addPoint(point,true,shift);



        // call it again after one second
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
    },
    cache: false
});
```

}

And my array returned by json are like these....  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFoTV.jpg.

I want them all to be printed on my high chart.. but my chart is not working...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUOy5.jpg

Thanks :)

Comment: And the chart is, no doubt dynamic !!!

Comment: Help ????????????????

Comment: Your "array returned by json" seem to be invalid. It could be formatted as a two dimensional array, for example `[[1,0],[3,2],[1,2]]` to be valid JS, or inside an object to be JSON... And have you opened your console to see what exact problems you are having with your chart?

Comment: Console shows nothing... and sir i have no idea how to put that inside a two dimensional array !!!

Comment: Maybe you should read how to create JSON in your backend language? Use some online JSON parsers, to see what kind of errors you have. You can find example of JSONP [here](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json). When you remove `callback()` and all comments you will get proper JSON example.